# GitLab LDAP login with single sign-on and auto blocking

Tags: gitlab

I'm trying to conifigure my GitLab CE install, so users can only log in using LDAP, GitLab creates their account automatically but blocks them until the administrator approves.  My LDAP config is working fine, but LDAP users are not blocked and the standard login is still shown.

```
gitlab_rails['allow_single_sign_on'] = true
gitlab_rails['block_auto_created_users'] = true
gitlab_rails['signin_enabled'] = false
gitlab_rails['signup_enabled'] = false
```

I've tried 7.3.2 and 7.4.0.  I'm using the omnibus install.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to set this option to `false`:

```
gitlab_rails['block_auto_created_users'] = true
```